# Win7 64bit cx_Oracle cx_Oracle.pyd not found

Tags: python, windows, oracle

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle DB 11.2g from Python 3.5.
I tried my luck with cx_Oracle. Other means are welcome if you have a better option. Here you can see that I have tried many routes to my cause.

I downloaded MS Windows installer 3.5 from
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.2.1
Read from a blogpost that after installation I should put cx_Oracle.pyd file to pythonpath. But I only found testing and sample files in its cx_Oracle-wininst.log file? Not even setup.py was found from which I could have tried to build it using cx_Oracle-doc\BUILD.txt that the installer left behind.

This was the best advice I was able to find:
http://prasoon11.blogspot.fi/

And before that I did try:
pip install cx_Oracle
failed with error code 1
building 'cx_Oracle' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

To work around that error I ended up here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
cx_Oracle-5.2.1+oci12c-cp35-none-win32.whl

How do I know which dll it is trying to use? It seems that it finds some dll (how do I find it?) but probably because the driver is oci12 but my instant client dll from Oracle is 11g. I think Oracle instant client 12c will work also with Oracle11g DB. How do I tell Python3 that is using this driver: cx_Oracle-5.2.1+oci12c-cp35-none-win32.whl to use the Oracle instantclient 12c that I downloaded?
Or alternatively can I get an oracle 11g cx_Oracle from somewhere?

In python3 code I tried this to make cx_oracle to find oci.dll:

```
import os
os.environ["ORACLE_HOME"] = "path to folder containing oci.dll"

import cx_Oracle 
#dostuff
```

but I got this error:
ImportError: DLL load failed: given procedure not found.
Does cx_Oracle use registry to find oci.dll?

Answer (score -1):

You can get 11g cx here: https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/?q=cx_oracle-11g

At first glance it seems that you are telling your library to work from the document folder which means that you have to go into the odbc and tell it to use the directory where you have oracle installed and python to read as document store. Does look like a simple answer, but maybe you just missed something little like that. Also double check that your paths are in both your system variables and in your user account, are you logged in as admin? I'll look around some more. but that is at least a start with the download from sourceforge.